# cake 2.3.x create menu

Tags: cakephp, menu

I need to help with add menu to my apps.
I use cake 2.3.8. I tried to use MenuHelper from this article http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/alkemann/2009/02/04/menuhelper.

I add this class to lib>Cake>View as MenuHelper.php
Next I added from `AppsController $helpers =>array('Menu');`

But I don't know what I should to do next. I tried use

```
$menu->add('link_list','title','url');
```

in my view or layout but cake doesn't view $menu variable. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're using the CakePHP 1.x syntax in your snippet, hence it doesn't work. In CakePHP 2.x, helpers are exposed as a property in the view and you have to use `$this->Menu->add('link_list','title','url');`.

Comment: But I should to adding sth to default cake? Or it's included already?

Comment: What do you mean with "adding sth to default cake"? You just have to add your helper to the `$helpers` array of either a specific controller, or your `AppController` if the helper should be available in all views. One thing I just noticed is that you should move your helper to the `app/View/Helper` folder because `lib/Cake` shouldn't be modified.